# Numerical Methods for eigen values of $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been writing a linear algebra library in c# for a while as an intellectual exercise and its gotten vastly more sophisticated that I originally thought it would and when I started adding methods for eigenvalues/eigenvectors when I noticed that if I use the Complex number type my methods for finding the eigenvalues no longer work and the program just runs forever or return junk data. So that leads me to the follow question:

Is there a good(*) way to find the eigenvalues of a general matrix  $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$?

note: I have methods for dealing with real valued matrices that work just fine and get all eigenvalues(including complex eigenvalues) but I'm looking for something that works on or is specialized for complex valued matrices.

(*) good meaning one that returns the eigenvalues as expected. I'm not looking for the fastest / most complicated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm has a couple.

Comment: unfortunately they all require specific forms/properties. I'm looking for a general method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small to medium-size dense eigenvalue problems, I believe the [QR algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) is the gold standard.  This method works by using orthogonal similarity transformations to compute the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_form) of the matrix under analysis, which is an eigenvalue-revealing factorization.  You can find more information about it in lots of places online, such as [these notes](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter3.pdf).  There are also good discussions in the following books:

- *The Matrix Eigenvalue Problem:  GR and Krylov Subspace Methods* by Watkins
- *Numerical Liner Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau
- *Matrix Computations* by Golub and Van Loan

A naive implementation of the QR algorithm is likely to be quite slow.  In addition to the basic theory, these resources also discuss ingredients that go into practical QR algorithms, such as preliminary reduction to Hessenberg form and the incorporation of shifts to speed up convergence.